# How to reroute url to different url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way of rerouting this:

```
domain.com/stsl
```

To this:

```
domain.com/about.php?info=stsl
```

How do I do that through .htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

Put this rule in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^stsl$ /about.php?info=stsl [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure **mod_rewrite** is enabled ?

Comment: @elemelas Did you find something about your problem ?